# grid issue with images

Tags: css, image, layout, grid

I am using columns and trying to line up 4 divs with images  using percentages for widths.

It's working fine but with one problem, I have 4 columns with a div element and with an image.

All columns have a padding right except the last one.

If you look at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mtgAI

the right div is bigger. I know the issue is with the last div not having  right padding,

the last column is now bigger. Any ways to get around this?

Comment: So why exactly is it that you aren't adding padding to the last one?

Comment: well try and wrap these div in a single <tr> having multiple <td> for each div individually and then put them in linearity.Hope this works. And then give certain space to every <td>. I know I have gone old school for it. But just give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lloan Alas had a good idea, unfortunately the `padding` values should be the same. Try this:

```
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The `[class*='col-']:last-of-type` is not necessary. Maybe there is a better solution, but I hope it can help you. :)

Comment: that worked... the reason i had the last one with no padding, is to have them equal on both sides. it was working without images.